# SVG with pattern and image element conversion to PNG Image failed

Tags: jquery, svg, raphael

I am trying to covert svg generated with Raphael.js into PNG image. Well, I converted the svg into image when svg has no pattern and image component. Then again when I add these two component into SVG something goes wrong and conversion fails.**Complete fiddle is** [here](http://jsfiddle.net/eeuUp/1/). Even if I save the generated svg and open in browser without conversion to image the image and patter is not rendered.

**The code snippet is :**

```
var r = Raphael(document.getElementById("cus"), 390, 253);
    r.setViewBox(-5, -2, 228, 306);
    for (var outline in doorMatOutline) {
        var path = r.path(doorMatOutline[outline].path);
        //path.attr({fill: 'url('+patternuri+')'}); //adding pattern        
    }
    //adding image
    var img = r.image(imageuri, 5 ,10 ,100 ,100);

    var svg = $('#cus').html().replace(/>\s+/g, ">").replace(/\s+</g, "<");

    canvg('cvs', svg, {
        ignoreMouse: true,
        ignoreAnimation: true
    });

    var canvas = document.getElementById('cvs');
    var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

    $("#resImg").attr('src', img);
    $("#cus").hide();
```

Answer (score 4):

I have solved this here http://jsfiddle.net/fktGL/1/,  first I had to change the svg attribute from

`xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"`

to

```
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
```

as the svg wasn't validating on the W3C validation service and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561270/error-on-line-39-at-column-26-namespace-prefix-xlink-for-href-on-script-is-not) is a stackoverflow explaining that a change is required.

I then had to add some timeouts to allow the SVG to render properly. I understand this is because the image has been drawn in the SVG & canvas but both need some time to render the image. My solution my not work perfectly on slower devices( an increase in the timeouts would help), but I don't know another way to get around this (welcome any comments/improvements).

Here is the final snipit

```
var r = Raphael(document.getElementById("cus"), 390, 253);
r.setViewBox(-5, -2, 228, 306);
for (var outline in doorMatOutline) {
    var path = r.path(doorMatOutline[outline].path);
    path.attr({
        fill: 'url(' + patternuri + ')'
    });
}

$('#cus svg').removeAttr('xmlns');

// If not IE
if(/*@cc_on!@*/false){
    $('#cus svg').attr('xmlns:xlink',"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink");
}


// First timeout needed to render svg (I think)
setTimeout(function(){ 
    var svg = $('#cus').html();
    window.svg = svg;
    canvg(document.getElementById('cvs'), svg);
    // annother delay required after canvg
    setTimeout(function(){
        var canvas = document.getElementById('cvs'),
            img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        $("#resImg").attr('src', img);
        //$("#cus").hide();
        console.log("ending... ");
    },100)
},100);
```

Comment: Image look like tile in png.

Comment: It works in firefox and chrome. There are errors in IE relating to the canvg script. I'll look but not sure if there will be an easy fix for that.

Comment: Updated answer to work in IE, hopefully it will work for you know.